# Upload files in Symfony form

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload, symfony-forms

I have a problem with upload files from form.
What am i doing wrong ?

Error is:

> Expected argument of type "App\Entity\Image", "instance of
> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile" given at property
> path "files".
>
> Form->handleRequest(object(Request)) in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\biuro\src\Controller\OfferController.php (line 29)

My code:

class OfferType:

```
class OfferType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class)
            ->add('description', TextareaType::class)
            ->add('files',FileType::class, [
                'multiple' => true
                ]
            )
```

class OfferController:

```
 class OfferController extends AbstractController
{
   public function createOffer(Request $request) {
 
        $offer = new Offer();
        $form = $this->createForm(OfferType::class, $offer);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
```

class entity Offer:

```
class Offer
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Image", mappedBy="offer", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $files;
```

Template:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>Nazwa:</th>
        <td>{{ form_widget(form.name) }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Opis:</th>
        <td>{{ form_widget(form.description) }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Zdjęcia:</th>
        <td>{{ form_widget(form.files) }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <td>{{ form_widget(form.save) }}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the files provided by the `files` field in your form are of type `UploadedFile`, while the entity property mapped to this field, `Offer::$files`, expects objects of type `Image` (which is incompatible with `UploadedFile`, resulting the error you experience). Without help, Symfony can't know how to **transform** the received `UploadedFile` objects into the expected `Image` objects. You will have to tell Symfony how to do this yourself.

Luckily, the Symfony Form component provides a relatively easy way to do this in the form of *Data Transformers*. [Here's an example](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html#example-2-transforming-an-issue-number-into-an-issue-entity) of how to implement such a transformer for your use case.

Comment: I resolved my problem this:
https://geekster.pl/symfony/upload-wielu-plikow/

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the bundle `VichUploader`

```
composer require vich/uploader-bundle
```

```
# config/services.yaml
parameters:
    app.path.product_images: /uploads/images/products
    # ...

# config/packages/vich_uploader.yaml
vich_uploader:
    # ...
    mappings:
        product_images:
            uri_prefix:         '%app.path.product_images%'
            upload_destination: '%kernel.project_dir%/public%app.path.product_images%'
``
```